# Creating backups with tar.gz and rsync

Tags: debian, rsync, tar

I'm trying to use this bash script to create and send the tar.gz file to my backup server, some reason it doesn't seem to copy it, is there a better solution to what I'm trying to do?

I'd rather have it compressed before I send it over the network

```sh
#!/bin/bash
####################################
#
# Backup to NFS mount script.
#
####################################

# What to backup. 
backup_files="/home/amp/.ampdata/instances/Towny/"

# Where to backup to.
dest="/home/amp/Backups"

# Create archive filename.
day=$(date +%A)
time=$(date +%H-%M)
file=$(file)
archive_file="$file-$day-$time.tgz"

# Print start status message.
echo "Backing up $backup_files to $dest/$archive_file"
date
echo

# Backup the files using tar.
tar czf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files
rsync $archive_file killbots@192.168.2.54:~/backup
# Print end status message.
echo
echo "Backup finished"
date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere in your script you refer to `$dest/$archive_file` as the file you wish to create and copy, *except* in the `rsync` command that is supposed to copy it to the other host. Fix the call to `rsync` and try again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show us what actually happens to make you believe that "it doesn't copy it".

Having said that, the use of both `tar` and `rsync` together is unusual. `rsync` would normally be used on a tree of files itself, and it will only copy what it needs to copy, taking into account what is already there (only sends differences).

You're not wanting to do that: you are wanting to just send this tar.gz file every time. So I question the point of using `rsync`.

This line in your script is wrong:

```
file=$(file)
```

It is executing the command `file` and putting the output in a variable called file. By itself that will be error output on stderr and nothing on stdout, so `$file` remains empty. For the purposes of making progress I'll just assume this variable is set to the string "file".

Your script is doing this, once we resolve the contents of the variables:

```
tar czf /home/amp/Backups/file-Thursday-21-39 /home/amp/.ampdata/instances/Towny/
rsync file-Thursday-21-39 killbots@192.168.2.54:~/backup
```

So, as noted, you don't need to use both `tar` and `rsync`. You are using `tar` to store an archive locally and then sending it to a remote host. Why keep the local archive? How will you prevent them from filling up your local storage?

You can directly `tar` over an SSH connection:

```
# tar zcvf - /home/amp/.ampdata/instances/Towny/ | \
  ssh killbots@192.168.2.54 'cat > backup/file-Thursday-21-39.tar.gz'
```

Some other comments:

- "Dayname-HH-MM" isn't a very good format in my opinion. Consider something more obvious and sortable like YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS.tar.gz.
- By default SSH is not compressed but that's okay because your `tar` command used gzip compression. You might consider `tar`'s other compression formats like XZ, bzip2, zstd, etc.
- Complete backup programs have been made to do compressed, deduplicating, reliable backups. It's not always worth cooking up your own. You might consider looking into borgbackup or restic or similar.